# Dynamically change src string in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a list of items i need to display with an image. The list is over 100 items, i can sort by alphabet so i know the order. I need to display matching images with each item.

```html
<div *ngFor='let item of items; i = index>

 <span>{{item}} <img class={{i}} src='/images/i.png'>

</div>
```

So I want it to look like:

```
class='0' src='/images/0.png'
class='1' src='/images/1.png'
class='2' src='/images/2.png'
```

and so on to 100.

ANy help would be much appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; i = index'>
    <span>{{item}} <img class={{i}} src='/images/{{i}}.png'>
</div>
```

or

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; i = index'>
    <span>{{item}} <img class={{i}} [src]='"/images/" + i + ".png"'>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">

  <span>{{item}} <img class="{{i}}" src="/images/{{i}}.png"></span>

</div>
```

**Output:**

[image: Debug output]

Answer (score 0):

You can continue using **interpolation** like so

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; i = index'>
    <span>{{item}} <img class={{i}} src='/images/{{i}}.png'>
</div>
```

or you could use **property binding**

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items; i = index'>
    <span>{{item}} <img class={{i}} [src]='"/images/" + i + ".png"'>
</div>
```

Now Interpolation is a convenient alternative for property binding in many cases. Angular actually translates those interpolations into the corresponding property bindings before rendering the view.

There is no technical reason to prefer one form to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor='let item of items;let i = index;'>
    <span>{{item}} <img [class]="i" src='assets/images/{{i}}.png'>
</div>
```

I hope this will be useful.